# How do I get a USB Wi-fi D-link DWA-125 rev D1 rtl8188etv working?

Tags: 12.04, wireless, networking, drivers, usb

guys.
DWA-125 rev.D1, RTL8188ETV. Ubuntu 12.04 LTS. 
lsusb, iwconfig, ifconfig, ip addr, lshw -C network:

```
root@gugenot-MS-7597:~# lsusb
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 058f:6362 Alcor Micro Corp. Flash Card Reader/Writer
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 2001:330f D-Link Corp. 
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 09da:000a A4 Tech Co., Ltd Optical Mouse Opto 510D
root@gugenot-MS-7597:~# iwconfig 
lo        no wireless extensions.

eth0      no wireless extensions.

root@gugenot-MS-7597:~# ifconfig 
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 6c:62:6d:a7:a3:99  
          inet addr:192.168.137.109  Bcast:192.168.137.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::6e62:6dff:fea7:a399/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:3791 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:2394 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:3715856 (3.7 MB)  TX bytes:354575 (354.5 KB)
          Interrupt:43 Base address:0x6000 

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:16436  Metric:1
          RX packets:170 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:170 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:20868 (20.8 KB)  TX bytes:20868 (20.8 KB)

root@gugenot-MS-7597:~# ip addr
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 16436 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN 
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP qlen 1000
    link/ether 6c:62:6d:a7:a3:99 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.137.109/24 brd 192.168.137.255 scope global eth0
    inet6 fe80::6e62:6dff:fea7:a399/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
root@gugenot-MS-7597:~# lshw -C network
  *-network               
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8111/8168B PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:04:00.0
       logical name: eth0
       version: 06
       serial: 6c:62:6d:a7:a3:99
       size: 1Gbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=full firmware=rtl_nic/rtl8168e-2.fw ip=192.168.137.109 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=MII speed=1Gbit/s
       resources: irq:43 ioport:e800(size=256) memory:dcfff000-dcffffff memory:dcff8000-dcffbfff
```

RTL8188C_8192C_USB_linux_v4.0.2_9000.20130911 is installed without errors.

```
modprobe -r rtl8192cu
modprobe rtl8192cu swenc=1
echo "2001 330f" > /sys/bus/usb/drivers/rtl8192cu/new_id
iwconfig
```

dmesg | tail -20:

```
<pre><code>root@gugenot-MS-7597:~# dmesg | tail -20
[  116.464842] type=1400 audit(1383584988.604:28): apparmor="DENIED" operation="open" parent=1 profile="/usr/lib/telepathy/mission-control-5" name="/usr/share/gvfs/remote-volume-monitors/" pid=1894 comm="mission-control" requested_mask="r" denied_mask="r" fsuid=1000 ouid=0
[  406.018811] type=1400 audit(1383585279.029:29): apparmor="DENIED" operation="capable" parent=1 profile="/usr/sbin/cupsd" pid=900 comm="cupsd" pid=900 comm="cupsd" capability=36  capname="block_suspend"
[  944.530863] type=1400 audit(1383585819.155:30): apparmor="DENIED" operation="capable" parent=1 profile="/usr/sbin/cupsd" pid=900 comm="cupsd" pid=900 comm="cupsd" capability=36  capname="block_suspend"
[ 1487.813757] cfg80211: Calling CRDA to update world regulatory domain
[ 1487.845269] usbcore: registered new interface driver rtl8192cu
[ 1507.324866] rtl8192cu: Chip version 0x10
[ 1507.453467] rtl8192cu: MAC address: 00:00:**:**:**:**
[ 1507.453480] rtl8192cu: Board Type 7
[ 1507.453780] rtlwifi: rx_max_size 15360, rx_urb_num 8, in_ep 1</code></pre>
```

So, does it mean that driver is installed successfully? But iwconfig gives nothing for wlan0 again. 
Help me, please, avoid going back to Windows...

Answer (score 1):

You installed the rtl8192cu driver correctly but no wireless interface was created because rtl8192cu is incorrect for your device. Please get a temporary wired ethernet connection and do:

```
sudo apt-get install git
git clone https://github.com/purchae/rtl8188eu.git
cd rtl8188eu
make
sudo make install
sudo modprobe -r rtl8192cu
sudo modprobe 8188eu
```

When a later kernel version is installed by Update Manager, after the required reboot, re-compile:

```
cd rtl8188eu
make clean
make
sudo make install
sudo modprobe 8188eu
```

Answer (score 1):

I have the same D-Link DWA-125 rev.D1, but

```
lsusb
```

prints

```
...
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 2001:3310 D-Link Corp. 
...
```

**(pay attention to the ID)**

And to make it work I change file `rtl8188eu/os_dep/usb_intf.c`

```
-       {USB_DEVICE(0x2001, 0x330F)}, /* DLink DWA-125 REV D1 */
```

for:

```
+       {USB_DEVICE(0x2001, 0x3310)}, /* DLink DWA-125 REV D1 */
```

save it

```
sudo make
sudo make install
sudo modprobe -r 8188eu
sudo modprobe 8188eu
```

and now driver works for me :)

Answer (score 0):

The biggest thanks to you. Finally driver is installed. The only thing is that dongle doesn't work properly: after 7-10 seconds of downloading-nothing-or-nothing-doing-in-internet, icon in tray shows "no signal", ping goes to limitless.

```
gugenot@gugenot-MS-7597:~$ iwconfig 
eth0      no wireless extensions.

lo        no wireless extensions.

wlan0     IEEE 802.11bgn  ESSID:"Home2"  Nickname:"<WIFI@REALTEK>"
          Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.452 GHz  Access Point: **:**:**:**:**:**   
          Bit Rate:72.2 Mb/s   Sensitivity:0/0  
          Retry:off   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:off
          Link Quality=100/100  Signal level=97/100  Noise level=0/100
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:0   Missed beacon:0
```

Only by case I mentioned that if I start download something really big, my good internet exists as long as downloading process longs. What have I done wrong? 
Btw, in Windows it works perfect.

Comment: Copy and paste this command in the terminal (ctrl+alt+t)`wget -N -t 5 -T 10 http://dl.dropbox.com/u/57264241/wireless_script && chmod +x wireless_script && ./wireless_script`
It will download a script and create a file named wireless-info.tar.gz in your home folder with wireless information so we can see the condition of your wireless at this time and the Mac address, WPA key and WEP key are removed for your security,paste contents of the wireless-info.tar.gz file as a zip file at http://pastebin.com/. 
No internet
[url]http://ubuntuforums.org/showpost.php?p=12350385[/url]

Comment: http://pastebin.com/hZRVxj60 - when something big is downloading,
http://pastebin.com/1eqdSXyk - when nothing's done with computer for over 30 seconds.

Comment: Sorry I did not see chili555 already helping you, he is the best so I am going to stay out of it and let the expert help you.